# Can I prevent 'tsc' from reformatting JSON files?

Tags: typescript

I have a large and complex JSON file (auto-generated, no human intervention required).

In the source directory it's a single line with no whitespace (81k):

```
{"ver":{"maj":1,"min":0,"uri":"goui.net/phonenumbers/simple/validation_only","ver":1},"typ":[252,253],"svm":3, ...
```

But when I run `tsc -b` to build my project, the resulting file in the `dist/` directory has been reformatted to add spaces:

```
{ "ver": { "maj": 1, "min": 0, "uri": "goui.net/phonenumbers/simple/validation_only", "ver": 1 }, "typ": [252, 253], "svm": 3, ...
```

This adds about 20k to the file size and obviously I would like to avoid it.

I know it will gzip to about the same size, but that's not important to me. I want `tsc` to stop messing with things it should just be copying (unless there's a compelling reason such as poor browser support for needing to add spaces).

Is there a config option to change this poor behaviour? I see nothing likely in the `tsconfig.json` options.

Alternatively can I copy the file (Windows) in some way as part of the standard build command to avoid this?

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "*", "*.json"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

and (root config):

```
{
  "references": [
    { "path": "./src" },
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    "composite": true,                                   /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["es6"],                                      /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "NodeNext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "src",                                 /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",                      /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                           /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                                 /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "dist/",                                /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "removeComments": true,                              /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    "newLine": "lf",                                     /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                               /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Comment: You're specifically `include`-ing JSON files. Don't do that if you don't want TypeScript to read and process them. Use a real build tool to copy the files (or just xcopy them).

Comment: So you're saying that I can expect "including" a file to do some undocumented arbitrary transformation on it. *sigh*

So how can I integrate a plain file copy into my TypeScript build flow?

Comment: `"postbuild": "do whatever"`?

Comment: That doesn't work because I am referencing the file by name and compilation fails if it's not known to the compiler: 
""src/index.ts:19:26 - error TS6307: File 'C:/.../javascript-simple/src/simple_compact.json' is not listed within the file list of project 'C:/.../javascript-simple/src/tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.""

Comment: Try manually copying the orginal to overwrite the de-minified version under dist.  If the program under dist runs without error, then go ahead and automate the copy as part of "postbuild" as suggested by @jonrsharpe.  (However, if your whole release program under dist is going to undergo minimization anyway, then ...).

Comment: I tried this (see edit to question) but it just doesn't run the "postbuild" script. Is this a `yarn` vs `npm` thing perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Like other have mentioned, it's best to manually copy over the JSON files since the main goal of `tsc` is to compile TypeScript files into JavaScript files.

If you're using NPM you can modify your `package.json` file to set up a `postbuild` script that will copy over the JSON files for you, once the `tsc` command has finished compiling your TypeScript files.

```json
  {
    ...
    "scripts": {
      "build": "tsc -b",
      "postbuild": "cp ./src/*.json ./dist"
    },
    ...
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work (see edit to question).

Comment: @David why would `postbuild` be triggered by `yarn tsc`? Compare this answer's scripts to what you have. Also it looks like Yarn doesn't support the hooks anyway: https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts/.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?
"postbuild" looks like a workflow hook that's run after a build step.

Comment: I just changed the `tsc` script to:
`"tsc": "tsc -b src && yarn ncp src/simple_compact.json dist/simple_compact.json"` which should mean it will work with Windows and Linux.

Comment: But your build step _isn't called build_, @David - even if Yarn supported the hooks `post<script>` would only run after `<script>`.

Comment: Yes, but you're assuming I know how that mechanism works (if I knew that I wouldn't be having problems).

Answer (score 0):

Since workflow hooks are NPM specific and don't work with Yarn, a build system independent answer that works either with Yarn or NPM is to avoid things such as `postbuild`.

For the case of JSON files:

1. Accept that `tsc` will mess with your JSON files and there's nothing you can do to stop that.
2. Overwrite the mangled file afterwards.

The easiest way to do that is to chain the copy after the build step in the same script:

```json
"tsc": "tsc -b src && ncp src/simple_compact.json dist/simple_compact.json"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing. And note it's absolutely fine to have answers that cover both NPM and Yarn use-cases because it's not just about _you_ - the next person with the same question might be using either.

Comment: Right, and I want to have a `package.json` that's agnostic to using `npm` or `yarn`. The answer I've given is fine for both system. The answer about using `postbuild` is NOT. Thus my answer is more applicable when I don't know which system someone is using.